# My code isn't creating a pivot table for some reason

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long


'Declare Variables
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Data")

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)


Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
SourceType = xlDatabase, SourceData = PRange)


Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="SalesPivotTable")
```

I don't get any error but it just creates the sheet "PivotTable", but no Pivot Table is created on the sheet. Can anyone help? I want the table to use all used cells on the data sheet.

Comment: I think you want `pivotcaches.add` instead of create?

Comment: Comment out `On Error Resume Next`, and run your macro again.  Do you get any errors?  If so, which one and on which line?

Comment: I get a type mismatch on SourceData = PRange)

Comment: That line should be  `Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)`